# Random port in Filtered state for brief amount of time found using nmap , possible trojan?

Tags: security, port, malware

Nmap results show me port 3527 open for brief period of time and then it disappears.

I have a feeling this could be trojan communicating with mothership. Or something normal, but I cannot find much information about this port or beserver-msq-q

[image]

[image]

What should I do next? how do I investigate something like this?

**EDIT** filtered means that it is not open, neither closed. Could this be nmap bug?

**UPDATE** I ran nmap few more times, and bogus port keeps changing. It is never the same, so 3527 is not very descriptive of the problem.

**General info** server runs openvz template ubuntu server 12.04.

Comment: Check the machine itself to see which process is opening that port using netstat or other tools.

Comment: The port is reported as "filtered". As in its blocked from the scanner somewhere between the host doing the scanning and the host being scanned. I suspect you are misinterpreting the data.

Comment: @MatthewIfe yes, and to add to weirdness port keeps changing, I get at least 1 filtered port per scan it is never the same every 3-4 scans.

Comment: @ETL netstat wouldn't tell me much, if there is rootkit installed.

Comment: @RedBalloon - sure don't run it, and stay in mistery. Or run it and maybe it tells you more data. And maybe not, but at least you'll have tried something.

Comment: @ETL I tried it. I did research before posting this question. Is there a better tool than netstat?

Comment: @RedBalloon - you should review your posts, the only thing you mention anywhere as having done is nmap. You can use wireshark to see what traffic goes out filtering all the ports you know should send traffic and that will leave you with those that don't. You don't state what OS that server is so I can't tell you much about "other tools".

Comment: On Windows: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html   or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx

Comment: @ETL hey, thanks. And I've updated OP. I will add few more screenshots of what I've tried already.

Comment: No, the port is being actively resued somewhere between you and the host. This has very little to do with the server you are scanning.

Answer (score 0):

The port 3527 (tcp and udp) is used by Backup Exec Server in it default configuration. Do you have this software on your server?

If not, it could be a possible trojan which try to open some common ports in order to communicate with the outside or listen for a brief period of time.

Try to use the netstat command on your server to check what happens and what software is listening when you see the port 3527 is used.

Comment: If I had that software I wouldn't be worried, would I ? :)

I noticed port is never same, it keeps changing. Makes me think it is connection thing from my network to server network.

Comment: If you want to see what exactly happens, you have to put another known good box on the same network looking at the traffic with tcpdump in promiscuous mode and log all the traffic. You can use e.g. Wireshark to later analyze the dump if needed. For normal uses you could record traffic from the same host but if you think the kernel may be modified, you have to use external device to record the traffic.